# Menu hierarchy expansion behavior for child-link that is a child of multiple parent links

Tags: navigation

When adding a page that will have a menu-link that is a child of parent menu-link (parent-1) you are able to
select the 'Menu link title' and a 'Parent item' on that create/edit form.  The link appears
and behaves as expected (i.e. when the parent link is clicked and expands the child is shown below
and indented).

If a second menu-link' to this child page is added to a different parent-item (parent-2) by using:
'Home » Administration » Structure » Menus » Main menu >> Add link' which uses a 'node-path'
the child links now appear as a sub-link under Parent-1 and Parent-2.

But when the child of parent-1 is clicked the menu expansion will show the hierarchy 
expansion of parent-2. The expansion is always of parent-2 regardless of which parent-child 
link is clicked.

If a third parent-child pair is added, the hierarchy expansion is now always shown for the 
third parent-child set (i.e. that last parent-child pair added will be what expands).

Is this correct behavior or is there a fix/proper way of doing this such that the expansion is
done for the parent-child pair clicked?

Comment: does both the sub menu have the same ID?

Comment: I don't see any ID designation on the link-edit pages.  Can you please elaborate?